# org.mockito.Mockito.mock is not effective even though the args are correct

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am trying to unit test a springboot application I inherited.

Here is how I initialise the mocking part of the unit test:

```
public class ValidationServiceTest {

    private Logger LOG = null;
    private final Long INVALID_ID = -1L;
    private Long custId = 4;
    private String username = "foo";

    cRepository repo;
    Customer customer = null;
    ValidationService  = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        validationService = new ValidationService();
        customer = new Customer();
        customer.setUsername(username);
        customer.setCustId(custId);

        repo = mock(cRepository.class);
        when(repo.searchByUsername(any(String.class))).thenReturn(customer);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getCustIdTest() {
        Long result = .getCustId(username);
    }
}
```

Then in the production part, I have this line of code:

```
    public Long getCustId(String username) {

    // Here it breaks
    Customer customer = repo.searchByUsername(username);
    return customer.getCustId;
}
```

I know that the correct values(username, password, id) is passed to the code, by checking the logs. The problem is that the line above is returning a NullPointerException.

Is this something obviously wrong? I would expect it to return a customer with username "foo", but it doesnt.

Stack trace of the exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mypkg.db.ValidationService.getCustId(ValidationService.java:27)
>       at com.mypkg.db.ValidationServiceTest.getCustIdTest(ValidationServiceTest.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: Are you mocking the correct method?  You're mocking the `searchByUsername` method but calling the `findByUsername` method instead.

Comment: Also, just because you create a mock instance of `cRepository` (that doesn't respect Java naming conventions and is a terribly obscure name, BTW), doesn't mean that the production code uses that mock instance. Post the whole relevant code.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, thanks for mentioning...I fixed the typo.

Comment: @JBNizet, do you want the production code I suppose?

Comment: Educated guess: the production part is using field injection, hasn't had the mocked repository set on it and, as a result, has a null customerRepository so it gets a NullPointerException. Can you share the production part too?

Comment: @py_script not only. I would like to write your whole test, and especially the way you're injecting the mock instance into the object under test, that calls the mocked method. You should also, **always** post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added more details. Let me know if you need something else ;)

Comment: Show your whole test. Especially the way you're injecting the mock instance into the object under test.

Comment: Thats all the initialisation logic I have. Not sure what is missing :-/

Comment: The whole unit test (or at least the class, the variables, the init - if any - and your failing test method). Show it. Most likely, you could simply use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` to fix your problem, but unless you show the test, noone knows.

Comment: @py_script what you're missing is my repeated comment asking to post your **whole** test. From the very first line of the file to the very last line.

Comment: I will paste the whole file, even the things that look irrelevant to me. Give me some time

Comment: Ok made the code more readable, as I know it is in a bad state currently. I have pasted the whole unit test file here

Comment: What you posted isn't valid Java code. But it confirms what I thought. The test creates a mock instance of cRepository, but it doesn't set the cRepository used by ValidationService, which thus uses another different, non mocked instance of cRepository.

Comment: Hmm ok, what is the best way to make the service use the mocking object?

Comment: Pass it as argument to its constructor, or to a setter method, or use Mockito annotations, as documented to let Mockito inject it in the field. Not knowing anything about ValidationService doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, a setter method looks like the way to go. Thanks for helping out @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

In Spring may be your autoWired repository is an interface

```
public interface cRepo  extends MongoRepository<X ,String>{
```

which can not be mocked by

```
cRepo = mock(cRepository.class);
```

Comment: It is a org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository actually

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation, given that some parts of your code are missing, is, that you mock a `cRepository`, but don't inject it into your `ValidationService`, which would explain all that happens here.

Imagine that you are mocking a steering wheel to test a car - but you don't put it into the car you are testing, then of course, will throw a Nullpointer Exception when it tries to access the steering wheel, since it's not there, just lying around somewhere else, which doesn't help your test at all...

Normally, you can simply write something like this...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ValidationServiceTest {

   @Mock
   private CRepository cRepository; // the runner, see above, will automatically mock this now

   @InjectMocks
   private ValidationService validationService;  // The runner will create this and inject all the mocks into it

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
      Customer customer = new Customer();
      customer.setUsername("foo");
      customer.setCustId(4);
      when(cRepository.searchByUsername(any(String.class))).thenReturn(customer);

      Long result = validationService.getCustId(username);
      assert(result.equals(4));
}
```

This way, Mockito will create your mock object automatically and inject it into the validationService object.

Oh, and please UPPER-CASE your classes!

Comment: initMocks in your code will have absolutely no effect, since you do not declare any of your test members to be mocks. And if you use the MockitoJUnitRunner, you don't need it, since it will happen automatically.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that the mock is never used, I should use a constructor or a setter to make it happen